# MinGW fails to compile project with -lc, -lm and -lrt linker's flags

Tags: compiler-errors, mingw, mingw32

I'm trying to compile python bindings for [Kyoto Cabinet](http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/) with Mingw32 for Windows7. I have several dirs in my library path: C:/MinGW/lib folder and a folder with kiotocabinet.lib; MinGW finds its own libs successfully but if fails with three standard:

-lc -lrt -lm

It deals ok with -lpthread, with -lstdc++ and -lz (I installed libz for that).

How can I fix this?